# Citrix unable to start session in Firefox Quantum

Tags: database, browser-plugin

In order to access the database service [DBoD](https://www.dbod.de/db/) it is necessary to create a session through [Citrix Receiver](https://www.citrix.de/downloads/citrix-receiver/). But in Firefox this is no longer possible. Is this because "Citrix Receiver" was replaced by "Citrix Workspace"? And how to solve this problem for Firefox?

Here is the error message:

> Citrix Receiver cannot connect to the server. To resolve this issue,
>   please report this error to your help desk. Please verify that the ICA connection is available and that the server
>   address is present.

And here the same error in German language:

> Citrix Receiver kann keine Verbindung mit dem Server herstellen.
>   Melden Sie diesen Fehler dem Helpdesk, um das Problem zu beheben.
>   Überprüfen Sie, ob die ICA-Verbindung verfügbar und
>   die Serveradresse vorhanden ist.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Citrix blog
[Firefox 52 and Citrix Receiver for Web](https://www.citrix.com/blogs/2017/03/15/firefox-52-and-citrix-receiver-for-web/),
the reason for the problem is that Firefox version 52 has dropped support for NPAPI.
The advice given was:

> you have to edit the web.config file under the Receiver for Web
>   (RfWeb) site (typically C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Citrix\StoreWeb) to
>   activate the Citrix Receiver Launcher for Firefox 52.
>
> Open web.config using your preferred text editor and locate the line
>   highlighted in the screen shot:

[image]

> This is a regular expression specifying that the Citrix Receiver Launcher is used for Firefox 53 and later. Change the highlighted bit to (Firefox/((5[2-9]|[6789][0-9])|\d\d\d)) to make RfWeb use the Citrix Receiver Launcher on Windows and Mac for Firefox 52 onward.